# How to stop Div Moving out of the border Jquery draggable();

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

How to stop the div from moving out of the border div

Here is the code i got so far.

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#draggable").draggable({ grid: [50, 20] });
  });
  </script>
  <div id="drag_border">
  <div id="draggable" style="width:500; height:800">Drag me</div>
  </div>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `containment`. E.g.

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
  grid: [50, 20],
  containment: 'parent'
});
```

**Edit:**

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9T4Gv/).

Remember, you're using a grid, so you won't reach the edges unless you calculate the width and height of your box to match that grid.

Comment: that stops it from moving down from it position.

Comment: Then you need to expand the height of your parent DIV.